# SQLite rowid alias in FTS table

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

[Here](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) it says that if I specify an INTEGER PRIMARY key column it will be used as an alias for rowid. For normal tables it works well, but for virtual FTS tables it does not.

Is there a way to use a rowid alias somehow?

Im using SQLite on Android and I would like to use the _id name for this column.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That documentation applies only to 'real' SQLite tables.

With FTS tables, data types are ignored; all columns are intended to be used for text.
FTS tables [do have an internal rowid column](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_3) (also called `docid`), but it is not possible to rename it.